# How to Change the SelectedItem Foreground Text of ListBox Item

Tags: xaml, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, listbox, textblock

I have the following ListBox below. I am not sure how to change the Foreground of a selected item's textblock text when an item is selected, and then back to the original foreground color when an item is unselected (most likely occurring when another item in the ListBox is selected afterwards)?

```
<ListBox Name="ListBox" SelectionMode="Single" ItemsSource="{Binding}" Margin="{Binding}"
                     toolkit:TiltEffect.IsTiltEnabled="True" SelectionChanged="ListBox_SelectionChanged" >
                    <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
                        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                            <toolkit:WrapPanel ItemWidth="159" ItemHeight="Auto" />
                        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
                    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical"  >
                                <Image Source="{Binding Thumbnail}" Width="155" Height="155" />
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" TextWrapping="Wrap" FontSize="{StaticResource PhoneFontSizeNormal}" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" />
                            </StackPanel>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                </ListBox>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to edit `ItemContainerStyle` (Edit additional templates > Edit generated Item Container (ItemContainerStyle)).

Within `ItemContainerStyle` is `Selected` visual state and you can change it.

```
<Style x:Key="ListBoxItemStyle1" TargetType="ListBoxItem">
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0"/>
    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Transparent"/>
    <Setter Property="Padding" Value="0"/>
    <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Left"/>
    <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Top"/>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="ListBoxItem">
                <Border x:Name="LayoutRoot" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalAlignment}" VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalAlignment}">
                    <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                            <VisualState x:Name="Normal"/>
                            <VisualState x:Name="MouseOver"/>
                            <VisualState x:Name="Disabled">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background" Storyboard.TargetName="LayoutRoot">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource TransparentBrush}"/>
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" To=".5" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Storyboard.TargetName="ContentContainer"/>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                        </VisualStateGroup>
                        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="SelectionStates">
                            <VisualState x:Name="Unselected"/>
                            <VisualState x:Name="Selected">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground" Storyboard.TargetName="ContentContainer">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="YOUR_NEW_COLOR"/>
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                        </VisualStateGroup>
                    </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                    <ContentControl x:Name="ContentContainer" ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplate}" Content="{TemplateBinding Content}" Foreground="{TemplateBinding Foreground}" HorizontalContentAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}" VerticalContentAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"/>
                </Border>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Comment: Alright. I don't see where I can select any options to edit the `ItemContainerStyle`? Either way, when I insert your code snippet into my Page Resources Element I am getting an error? Also, since this is targeting `ListBoxItem` where should I reference this?

Comment: Retracting my previous comment! I simply added `ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource ListBoxItemStyle1}"` within my ListBox element parameters, and changed the `Foreground` property of the `ListBoxItemStyle1` accordingly, and everything works great! I would still like to know how you get the ItemContainerStyle from the steps you listed above?

Comment: No, this is Visual Studio.

Answer (score 2):

I am considering that the `ItemsSource` of your `ListBox` is bound to an `ObservableCollection` of an examle class `test.cs` as below

```
ObservableCollection<test> coll = new ObservableCollection<test>();
```

and the `DataContext` is `ListBox.DataContext = coll;`

Bind the `Foreground` property of your `TextBlock` in the `ListBoxItemTemplate`

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" Foreground="{Binding foreground}" TextWrapping="Wrap" FontSize="{StaticResource PhoneFontSizeNormal}" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" />
```

Now define your `SelectionChanged` event

```
private void ListBox_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    test tItem = (sender as ListBox).SelectedItem as test;
    test.foreground = "#FFCB202D"; //this will change the color of the TextBlock
}
```

Make sure you extend your class `test.cs` with `INotifyPropertyChanged` and define the property `foreground` with the same or else dynamic changes will not be reflected.

```
    private string tmpforeground;
    public string foreground
    {
        get
        {
            return tmpforeground;
        }

        set
        {
            if (tmpforeground== value)
                return;
            tmpforeground= value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("foreground");
        }
    }
```

Also note that if you want the textblock to change color to green on one tap and then change its color again by tapping again, `SelectionChanged` event won't work, because it works only when a different item is selected. So if you want change of color on consecutive taps then use `Tap` event instead

```
<ListBox Name="ListBox" SelectionMode="Single" ItemsSource="{Binding}" Margin="{Binding}"
                 toolkit:TiltEffect.IsTiltEnabled="True" Tap="ListBox_Tap" >

private void ListBox_Tap(object sender, System.Windows.Input.GestureEventArgs e)
{
    test tItem = (sender as ListBox).SelectedItem as test;
    test.foreground = "#FFCB202D";
}
```